# Find decryption formula with already known encryption formula in block cipher operation mode context

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes, des

I have this formula for encryption phase of a [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) using AES or DES encoder:

[image: encryption formula]

So the question is how can find decryption formula for this.
And what is the general workflow to solve problems like this?

Comment: D(C_1 xor M_0, K) xor C_0. The question and answer have nothing to do with AES or DES, it applies to any block cipher.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk can you explain the general solution plz?

Comment: You're trying to solve for M_1. The xor operation is self-inverting, that is y xor y = 0. The decrypt operation is the inverse of the encrypt operation. The rest follows from these two facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two XOR operations here, one prior to encryption and one afterwards.

[image]

The decryption is the reversal of the encryption operation:

[image]

Which means you have to first XOR `C1` with the same key (`M0`) to get the value to decrypt, and then XOR the decrypted value (with `C0`) to get the original plaintext value.

```
M1 = D(C1 ⊕ M0, K) ⊕ C0
```